# JavaScript TypeError: says a CSS declaration returns as "null"

Tags: javascript, css, function

Here is the code in question that seems to be causing issues:

```
        player.style.height = playerH + "px";
        function trackXY(){
        for(let i=0; i<pokeS.length; i++){
        let pokeS = document.getElementsByClassName('pikaStyle' + i);
        let xPlayer = parseInt(player.style.left + .5*player.style.width);
        let yPlayer = parseInt(player.style.top + .5*player.style.height);
        let xpokeS = parseInt(pokeS.style.left + .5*pokeS.style.width);
        let ypokeS = parseInt(pokeS.style.top + .5*pokeS.style.height);
        let rPlayer = .5*parseInt(player.style.height);
        let rpokeS = .5*parseInt(pokeS.style.height);
        let dX = xpokeS - xPlayer;
        let dY = ypokeS - yPlayer;
        let distance = Math.sqrt((dX*dX)+(dY*dY))
        if(distance <= (rpokeS+rPlayer)){
            alert("collison!" + pokeS.id);
        player.style.height = parseInt(player.style.height) + .5*parseInt(pokeS.style.height);
        }
      }
    }
```

it keeps either returning that "style" cannot be read or "left" is undefined. can someone advise? thanks.

Comment: Wonder if my answer solve your problem:) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `window.getComputedStyle()` and `getPropertyValue` to get the style. You can't directly use `element.style.height`, it will return nothing.

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.

In your code, use:

```
window.getComputedStyle(player).getPropertyValue('height') 
window.getComputedStyle(pokeS).getPropertyValue('height')
```

Example:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div')
//return nothing
//console.log( div.style.height)
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('height'))
```

```css
div{
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```